# Call web service in javascript template

Tags: javascript, web-services, templates, ejs

Is it possible to call a Web Service inside an .ejs file and print the returned value?
Like in python:

```
 req =requests.get(link, timeout=20)
 response = req.text
 data = json.loads(response)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with Ajax request.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "urltoyourservice.xml"
    dataType: "xml",
 }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 });
```